# Problems updating weather indicator

Tags: 12.04, command-line, updates, package-management, update-manager

I can not update Weather Indicator with Update Manager. This is the terminal log:

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed. perl:
warning: Please check that your locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG = "sr_RS.utf_8_latin"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory perl:
warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your
locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),     LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG =
"sr_RS.utf_8_latin"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory perl:
warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your
locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),     LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG =
"sr_RS.utf_8_latin"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory perl:
warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your
locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),     LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG =
"sr_RS.utf_8_latin"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the andard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory Setting
up indicator-weather (11.11.28-0ubuntu1.1) ... Installing
indicator-specific icons... Installing indicator dconf schema... cp:
cannot stat
`/usr/share/indicator-weather/indicator-weather.gschema.xml': No such
file or directory dpkg: error processing indicator-weather
(--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: 
indicator-weather Error in function:  SystemError: E:Sub-process
/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) Setting up indicator-weather
(11.11.28-0ubuntu1.1) ... Installing indicator-specific icons...
Installing indicator dconf schema... cp: cannot stat
`**/usr/share/indicator-weather/indicator-weather.gschema.xml**': No such
file or directory dpkg: error processing indicator-weather
(--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
error exit status 1
```

The file that I bold really does not exist. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had a very similar problem with `indicator-weather` recently at [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2045661) and their submitted log is nearly identical to yours. The simple advice on that forum was to try to complete the update with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and if that didn't work remove `indicator-weather` and purge its configuration files with

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-weather
```

and then simply run `sudo apt-get update` and reinstall it. There are no other error codes in the logs that would suggest any more complicated fixes are necessary and the purge of the configuration files should solve the issue as it did at the other forum.

Comment: That is my thread on Ubuntu Forums, but thanks.